# Multiple ImageView's that allow for deletion

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

I am currently trying to add multiple imageviews like in this picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ5c6.png) to a view controller. I would also like the option to be able to delete specific images, and also have the whole view controller in a scrollview incase the user wants to add numerous images.

So far I have one imageview that can be set to either a picture from the camera or from the photo library, what I would like is when a user add's a image, another option displays next to it to upload another image such as the picture in the link I provided.

I am currently using the Xcode 5 with storyboards and developing for iOS 7 also.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `UICollectionView` !

Reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html

It will allow you to add functionalities like delete or add for example (w/ ScrollView ;) )!